# Не отображается фото на GitHub

Tags: html, github

Всем привет народ, написал код на чистом HTML, перешел в ГитХаб, получил адрес сайта и фото не отображается. Впринципе ошибка ясна, возможно я указал локальный адрес в текстовом редакторе, а Гит локалку не читает...
Все же хочется услышать мнение экспертов! Всем Добра!

Comment: На основании какой информации эксперты должны делать какие-то выводы?

Comment: Хотел бы узнать в чем ошибка? Почему фото не отображается

Comment: Вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос. А по имеющейся информации можно только гадать

Comment: Все доки из Атома загрузил на Гит, получается ссылку на фото лучше из сети указывать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большинстве случаев, если Вы верстаете сайт локально, вы используете *относительные* ссылки.

Пускай у Вас есть `index.html`, в корневой директории. Там же есть директория `images`, а в ней лежит `photo.jpg`

Тогда относительая ссылка в `index.html` выглядит как

```
    <img src="images/photo.jpg" />
```

Сделанная таким образом ссылка будет работать независимо от того, какой адрес у сайта - локальный или на хостинге.

Кроме относительных ссылок бывают абсолютные: они включают адрес сайта, и, таким образом, позволяют на одном сайте показать фоточку с другого.

выглядит примерно так:

```
    <img src="http://mysite.ru/images/photo.jpg" />
```

Проверьте Ваши ссылки!

Comment: Спасибо большое! У меня получилось!